# Angular 4 - Compiler cannot find a node module module in a component but there is another module that can import it sucessfully

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am dealing with some angular 4 app and I would like to import some modules in `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`. The problem is that even though I have a custom module that has successfully imported the modules, another module of mine fails to import it and gives warnings like this one:
`WARNING in ./src/app/main/layout/fail/fail/fail.component.ts
151:83-96 "export 'NgbTimeStruct' was not found in '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'`
I am very certain that it's properly installed as I said I have another module that can import it with no problem, but what have I missed? I have already included the modules and components needed in the `module.ts` and `component.ts` files!

These are the ones I need to solve:
`CalendarEvent` from `angular-calendar`;
`NgbDateStruct` and `NgbTimeStruct` from `@ngx-translate/core`

Here are my codes:

Module successfully imported the modules:

success.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SuccessComponent } from './success.component';
import { SuccessRoutingModule } from './successrouting.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CalendarModule } from 'angular-calendar';
import { UtilsModule } from '../util/module';
import { FailModule } from '../../fail/fail/fail.module';
//import { FailComponent } from '../../event/eventmodify/eventmodify.component'; // I am trying to use the failed module in this module
import { NgbModalModule, NgbDatepickerModule, NgbTimepickerModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ElementsModule } from '../../../../shared/components/elements/elements.module';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SuccessDemoRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModalModule.forRoot(),
    NgbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    NgbTimepickerModule.forRoot(),
    CalendarModule.forRoot(),
    UtilsModule,
    FailModule,
    ElementsModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [SuccessDemoComponent],
  exports: [SuccessDemoComponent]
})
export class SuccessModule { }
```

success.component.ts:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ViewChild, 
TemplateRef, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { jqxDataTableComponent } from 'jqwidgets-framework/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxdatatable';
import { EventModifyComponent } from '../../event/eventmodify/eventmodify.component';
import { EventValue } from '../../../service/event/structure/event.value';
import { EventService } from '../../../service/event/event.service.promise';
import { ValidateUtil } from '../../../../shared/validate/validate.util';
import { GeneralService } from 
'../../../service/general/general.service.promise';
import { GeneralValue } from '../../../service/general/structure/general.value';
import { ResponseValue } from '../../../service/event/structure/response.value';
import * as myGlobal from '../../../../shared/global/global';
import { WindowComponent } from '../../../../shared/components/elements/window/window.component';

import { startOfDay, endOfDay, subDays, addDays, endOfMonth, isSameDay, isSameMonth, addHours, getMinutes, getHours, getDate, getMonth, getYear, setSeconds, setMinutes, setHours, setDate, setMonth, setYear } from 'date-fns';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { NgbModal, NgbDateStruct, NgbTimeStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CalendarEvent, CalendarEventAction, CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent} from 'angular-calendar';

import 'angular-calendar/dist/css/angular-calendar.css';

... //out of the failed ones I need only NgbModal is included in the constructor
```

Module failed to import the modules:

fail.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FailComponent } from './fail.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CalendarModule } from 'angular-calendar';
import { SuccessModule } from '../../success/success/success.module';
import { UtilsModule } from '../../success/util/module';
import { NgbModalModule, NgbDatepickerModule, NgbTimepickerModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ElementsModule } from '../../../../shared/components/elements/elements.module';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    CalendarModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModalModule.forRoot(),
    NgbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    NgbTimepickerModule.forRoot(),
    UtilsModule,
    ElementsModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [FailComponent],
  exports: [FailComponent]
})
export class FailModule { }
```

fail.component.ts:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ViewChild, TemplateRef, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { jqxDataTableComponent } from 'jqwidgets-framework/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxdatatable';
import { EventValue } from '../../../service/event/structure/event.value';
import { EventService } from '../../../service/event/event.service.promise';
import { ValidateUtil } from '../../../../shared/validate/validate.util';
import { GeneralService } from '../../../service/general/general.service.promise';
import { GeneralValue } from '../../../service/general/structure/general.value';
import { ResponseValue } from '../../../service/event/structure/response.value';
import * as myGlobal from '../../../../shared/global/global';
import { WindowComponent } from '../../../../shared/components/elements/window/window.component';

import { startOfDay, endOfDay, subDays, addDays, endOfMonth, isSameDay, isSameMonth, addHours, getMinutes, getHours, getDate, getMonth, getYear, setSeconds, setMinutes, setHours, setDate, setMonth, setYear } from 'date-fns';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { NgbModal, NgbDateStruct, NgbTimeStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CalendarEvent, CalendarEventAction, CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent} from 'angular-calendar';

... // Only NgbModal included as well
```

Any idea on how to make things work? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I double imported the modules and Angular doesn't like it. I removed the imports of the success module from the fail module then it works pretty well. I think if anyone who really needs the two custom modules to depend on each others they'd better not to import some modules like the `NgbModalModule` twice by importing in both modules.

And also I heard the best way for someone to do the sharing of the modules would be importing those into a shared module instead.